# Host a WMS service from MapProxy SQLite cache?

Tags: sqlite, cache, mapproxy

I'm trying to start a WMS server that would not have access to internet and for a source, I have the SQLite layers cache from MapProxy .

I read the manual and saw that I could probably work with a mbtiles cache as a source, but not really SQLite layers databases. It seems to me that some configuration of caches should allow to host the cache itself as a source but I have been unable to get it working. Am I missing something obvious? Is it even possible? Should I be using some other software?

Comment: MapProxy is a full compliant WMS server. Just read the documents  https://mapproxy.org/, start the service at localhost and then as documented "The WMS server is accessible at /service, /ows and /wms and it supports the WMS versions 1.0.0, 1.1.1 and 1.3.0."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation was misleading me. You can indeed host a wms server given a sqlite cache.

My problem was in my config. I specified the path wrong possibly in globals (used windows style \ instead of /). I got it working when i saw the folder structure it generated at the root of my disk.

I ended up with this config (my drive letter is E and using win 10):

```
grids:
  sim_webmercator:
    srs:  'EPSG:3857'
    bbox: [redacted]
    bbox_srs: 'EPSG:3857'
    num_levels: 14
    origin: nw

services:
  wms:
    srs: ['EPSG:3857']
    image_formats: ['image/jpeg']

layers:
  - name: my_cache
    title: my map
    sources: ['my_cache']

caches:
  my_cache:
    sources: []
    grids: ['sim_webmercator']
    format: 'image/jpeg'
    link_single_color_images: true
    cache:
      type: 'sqlite'
      directory: 'E:/full/path/to/my_cache'

globals:
  cache:
    meta_size: [1, 1]
    meta_buffer: 0
  image:
    paletted: true
```

At the location when i relied at global base dir location the cache was created at the root of E.

The my_cache folder structure has a folder called sim_webmercator in which are the tiles and tile_locks folder. Mapproxy generates both if there arent any.

Comment: Should I accept it as an answer?